# Get current item from QMutableListIterator

Tags: c++, qt

I can't dereference a QMutableListIterator like an STL iterator - with *it.

I'm trying to use QMutableListIterator::value() but my program crashes. What is the right way to do this?

```
QFileInfoList files;
// populate list
QListIterator<QFileInfo> it(files);
it.toFront();
QFileInfo = it_top.value();
// crash
```

The error is

```
ASSERT: "item_exists()" in file /usr/include/qt4/QtCore/qlist.h, line 778
```

Thanks

Comment: can you post some code with which you can reproduce the problem?

Comment: Yes, in fact I missed something out. Hang on

Comment: @MVG: I don't know Qt, but is it_top initialized properly?

Comment: I can call next(), hasNext(), anything else really without complaints.

Comment: Well, I have now got a workaround in place. I'll post a more informative question in the future if I can't fix things.

Comment: Would you care to post the code for `//populate list` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just checked the Qt documentation for "toFront" and it says:

> Moves the iterator to the front of the
>   container (before the first item).

http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qmutablelistiterator.html#toFront

The Qt Iterators are Java-style iterators which start before the items and end on the last item, the C++ style iterators begin on the first item and end after the last one.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the code you have shown.

The problem actually lies in `// populate list`

Actually *I guess* **no item gets populated** in the `QFileInfoList`. That's why you are getting the `ASSERT` when you try to access it.

And check for the `hasNext()` return value. Most possibly it will return false.

Hope it helps in someway..

Comment: Hey, thanks. hasNext() works fine, and the list is definitely populated ok. @Haplo's assessment is right, I think